# Is there a (sort of inverse security) valve which opens if one connected side has a pressure below a certain value?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, valves

Security valves with two connectors open if the pressure exceed a value x +/- tolerance on one side. I'd like to know if there's a mechanical valve which opens if the pressure on one side sinks below a certain value.

The use case is a system with a desired pressure d (e.g. 2 bar), but irregular pressure during operation (because it's based on bio mass fermentation) and a gas storage which stores extranous gas if the pressure is above 2 bar. This storage needs a value which can release pressure from the storage into the system if the pressure in the system sinks below the desired pressure.

Comment: This should answer a small portion of http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/which-components-to-use-for-a-co2-gas-storage, so it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [pressure regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_regulator) (and this is indeed what you need in your use case, but that is another question.) The regulator works so that over a range of flows, the pressure on the outlet side is kept constant.